# How to customised UIDocumentPickerViewController?

Tags: swift3, share, uiactionsheet, drive, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I'm using UIDocumentPickerViewController for derives(likes Dropbox, google etc.).

```
let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypeContent),String(kUTTypeItem)], in: .import)

    importMenu.delegate = self
    importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But now i'm trying to customised UIDocumentPickerViewController. How can i add more option in menu like camera, gallery etc.

I can't use bellow code because `UIDocumentMenuViewController` is deprecated now.

```
func addOption(withTitle title: String, 
         image: UIImage?, 
         order: UIDocumentMenuOrder, 
       handler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

Is there any other way that i can customised `UIDocumentPickerViewController` and add more option in that.

Thanks